# chrome Video Acceleration is not working on wayland

Tags: google-chrome, wayland, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to enable video acceleration in chrome

[My chrome://gpu output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0szNv.png) says that hardware acceleration is enabled but when I play video on youtube, the [hardware acceleration is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8YgJ.png)

```
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i3-1005G1 bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache:
    L2: 1024 KiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1202 min/max: 400/3400 cores: 1: 1219 2: 1203 3: 1201
    4: 1185
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (ICL GT1) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
```

```
murat@ubuntu:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.14 (libva 2.12.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 22.3.1 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointStats
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile1            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile3            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
```

Comment: have you tried it with X11?

Comment: Yes, but the result is the same